# How are per-day statistics computed on MtGox in the middle of the day?

Tags: exchanges, trading, mtgox

MtGox trades 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. Yet charts show daily charts and volume stats, especially intraday, when does the trading session begin and end on Mt. Gox, for reporting purposes? Also, what time zone.